# Syntax error, unexpected '$two_ssid' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' or ',' I have tried everything to no luck

Tags: php

I am working this code over here:

```
 fopen ("tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf", "w+");
  echo "network={
ssid="$two_ssid"
psk="$two_password"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
;}
shell_exec("cp /tmp/wpa_supplicant.conf"  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf);

}
```

I know it isn't the best, but hey, I am a newbie...and I am going mad over the error:

Syntax error, unexpected '$two_ssid' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' or ','

Please help, as I am really, really going mad over here, thanks!

Comment: You've got unescaped double-quotes in your double-quoted string

Comment: Thanks for your response!, upon risk of looking totally stupid...what does that mean?

Comment: Everything should be explained in the linked post

Comment: You're a lifesaver Phil, thanks!